# Is it possible to have zooming option in NVD3 charts as like in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I recently started using NVD3 charts and like to have zooming option like Highcharts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

There is a "Line Chart with View Finder" example that uses `nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()`. This chart type sports an additional "mini map" below the main chart that you can use to zoom and pan the chart:

See: [Line Chart with View Finder](http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html)

Comment: Do we have such feature for scatter charts? If not, how can we add it?

Answer (score 2):

You could apply this function to your nvd3 chart. It does not yield a draggable box to assist zooming like in Highcharts but it allows zooming by mouse scroll as shown here: [pan+zoom example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919). You will have to remove the transitions/delays from nvd3 to achieve smooth zooming. For now, you might have to do this manually by altering the nvd3 source file. There is a discussion about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067632/how-to-remove-nvd3-chart-resize-update-delay).

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqNkB/).

```
function addZoom(options) {
// scaleExtent
var scaleExtent = 10;

// parameters
var yAxis       = options.yAxis;
var xAxis       = options.xAxis;
var xDomain     = options.xDomain || xAxis.scale().domain;
var yDomain     = options.yDomain || yAxis.scale().domain;
var redraw      = options.redraw;
var svg         = options.svg;
var discrete    = options.discrete;

// scales
var xScale = xAxis.scale();
var yScale = yAxis.scale();

// min/max boundaries
var x_boundary = xScale.domain().slice();
var y_boundary = yScale.domain().slice();

// create d3 zoom handler
var d3zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();

// fix domain
function fixDomain(domain, boundary) {
    if (discrete) {
        domain[0] = parseInt(domain[0]);
        domain[1] = parseInt(domain[1]);
    }
    domain[0] = Math.min(Math.max(domain[0], boundary[0]), boundary[1] - boundary[1]/scaleExtent);
    domain[1] = Math.max(boundary[0] + boundary[1]/scaleExtent, Math.min(domain[1], boundary[1]));
    return domain;
};

// zoom event handler
function zoomed() {
    yDomain(fixDomain(yScale.domain(), y_boundary));
    xDomain(fixDomain(xScale.domain(), x_boundary));
    redraw();
};

// zoom event handler
function unzoomed() {
    xDomain(x_boundary);
    yDomain(y_boundary);
    redraw();
    d3zoom.scale(1);
    d3zoom.translate([0,0]);
};

// initialize wrapper
d3zoom.x(xScale)
      .y(yScale)
      .scaleExtent([1, scaleExtent])
      .on('zoom', zoomed);

// add handler
svg.call(d3zoom).on('dblclick.zoom', unzoomed);
};

// here chart is your nvd3 model
addZoom({
   xAxis  : chart.xAxis,
   yAxis  : chart.yAxis,
   yDomain: chart.yDomain,
   xDomain: chart.xDomain,
   redraw : function() { chart.update() },
   svg    : svg
});
```

Comment: I have update the fiddle. Could you please try it again and let me know if it works now for you.